# Emscripten Error when building to WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm using Unity 5.1

Whenever I build my game to WebGL, I get an error in the console

> Failed running "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\webglsupport/BuildTools/Emscripten_Win/python/2.7.5.3_64bit/python.exe"
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\webglsupport/BuildTools/Emscripten/emcc"
>   -Oz -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-invalid-offsetof -

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I believe I had the same issue. Turned out to be because I had a separate install of Python 2.7 installed on my machine.

Try to either uninstall your python installation (make sure the environment vars are gone) or remove all the environment variables that mention Python.

In my case I just did both since I no longer was doing active development in Python.